# SLRequest with C# in Xamarin.iOS project returned code:215 Bad Authenticated

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I tried a sample of xamarin.iOS on http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_the_social_framework/

but

```
twitterRequestButton.TouchUpInside += delegate {

            if (SLComposeViewController.IsAvailable (SLServiceKind.Twitter)) {

                var parameters = new NSDictionary ();
                var request = SLRequest.Create (SLServiceKind.Twitter,
                                                SLRequestMethod.Get,
                    new NSUrl ("http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/public_timeline.json"),
                                                parameters);

                request.PerformRequest ((data, response, error) => {

                    if (response.StatusCode == 200) {
                        InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                            resultsTextView.Text = data.ToString (); });

                    } else {
                        InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                            resultsTextView.Text = "Error: " + response.StatusCode.ToString (); });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

This SLRequest returned 215 code; Bad Authenticated.

I don't know why.

All I want to do is to get specific user's time line so if you have an idea about this, please help me.

Comment: do you have Twitter auth settings setup in the Settings app?  Are you trying to do this from the simulator or a device?

Comment: Thanks Jason, yeah I set my social account in setting app in my iOS simulator and I can post tweet and facebook but can't get timeline.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807221/get-twitter-friends-list/54838712#54838712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well -- for one thing `statuses/public_timeline` does not exist as an endpoint for version 1.1 of their API.  Maybe you like https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline or https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline?